# JPA/HIbernate Very Slow Query while JDBC/Postgres is Fast

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am running a spring boot application running Hibernate 5.4.2 and Postgresql 42.2.2 DB running on Heroku.

I am using JPARepository's default findAll() method to select my entire table. There are about ~50 entities and it's taking ~35 seconds. When I run a select all query using the Heroku CLI via terminal on the same machine, the query finishes in ~130milliseconds.

I have been trying to use JProfiler to pinpoint the problem. Looking at the query via JProfiler, I notice that the associated JDBC call takes about ~140ms which is close to the Heroku CLI. However the query itself still takes 35 seconds...

I have turned hibernate logging on and made sure that there are no other queries being sent. Also, I have tried to run the same query backing my application with a H2 database. The query returned in less than a hundred milliseconds.

See JProfiler query time https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAKwf.png

My entity is quite simple. There are no relationships to other classes so I dont think its a n+1 query problem.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class SqlEvent extends SerializedObjectRecord {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @NonNull
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NonNull
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NonNull
    private UUID uuid;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NonNull
    private UUID sqlCommandUuid;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NonNull
    private Instant timestamp;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NonNull
    private String avroSchemaFingerprint;
```

My service class

```java
    @Override
    @Timed(value = "service")
    public Collection<Pair> getAll(UUID commandId) {

    long start = System.nanoTime();

    List<SqlEvent> list = this.sqlEventRepository.findAll();
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = (end - start) / 1000000; #duration takes ~35000ms like Jprofiler says

    return convert(list);
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAKwf.png
```

Comment: Just checking - did you also run it without JProfiler and did it run just as slow? Profilers sometimes have the bad habit of impacting performance negatively.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Hey ! Yes, unfortunately, it is just as slow.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've just run into the same problem.